# jQuery Prev() Question

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

Sorry guys, I should have posted the script directly without cleaning it. Please check the updated script, it should now clear things up. Thanks!

Consider the following JavaScript :

```
    var selected = 0;
    var options = 0;

    $('.newListSelected').each(function() {

        selected = $(this).children('.selectedTxt');
        selected = selected.text();

        /* Everything before this line works completely fine */

        options = $(this).prev();

        options.find('option[value=' +selected+ ']').attr('selected', 'selected');

    }).remove();
```

And HTML :

```
<select name="type[]" style="display: none;">
    <optgroup>
        <option value="none">Select</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="First Group">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Second Group">
        <option value="10">Ten</option>
        <option value="20">Twenty</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<div class="newListSelected">
    <div class="selectedTxt">20</div>
    <ul class="newList">
        <!-- Other stuff here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do actually is adding the `selected` attribute to the corresponding select **option** that has the same value as the text in `.selectedTxt`. In the code above, it should add `selected="selected"` to `<option value="20">Twenty</option>`.

However its not performing as expected, I also tried adding `alert(option);` below `prev();` but it didn't output anything useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/HmLjw/ however... you can only have 1 option selected at a time... thats... what they're for, what are you actually trying to accomplice here?

Comment: Works for me. After I run the code, the option with `2` are selected. Only one option can be selected in a normal select box!

Comment: You cant select all elements as selected.

Answer (score 4):

The Javascript works fine, as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/4HsXp/

If you need to be able to select multiple items in a `select` element, you need to set the `multiple` and `size` attribute, like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select

---

**Edit:**

Attaching `console.log` statements to the new code still does not any problem. [Running it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQKXy/1/) gave me the correct output:

```
jQuery(select)
Original Value: none
New Value: 20
```

Comment: ...why didn't I think of that, oh well +1 :)

Comment: @user Updated, and *still* nothing seems to be wrong. Can you elaborate on what appears to be the problem?

Comment: @Yi Jiang Wired.. I use Firebug to check the elements but couldn't see any option that contain `selected="selected"` after executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but why couldn't you just select all option elements with proper selectors? If you want to select only some options, then you have to add extra selector attrbiutes.

```
$('select option').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```